# com.google.maps.android.MathUtil not found in android project

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, import, google-maps-api-2

I want to use google maps and try different functionnality in my android application. 
I want to use SphericalUtil package in my android project. 
I import it and add compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'to the gradle. There is not any error in the compilation but when I open the google maps in my application, it stopped and this error appear:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.MathUtil                                                                                    at com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil.computeHeading(SphericalUtil.java:45)

Can you help me please?